# Get the number of days between 2 dates using Javascript

Tags: javascript, date

actually the code works fine when the date is on the same month but i had a problem when the date is on the different month like 30/09/2015 and 01/10/2015 the number of days result is 2.(sorry for my bad english)

Here's the sample code:

```
var dtElem1 = '30/09/2015';
var dtElem2 = '01/10/2015';
var resultElem = frm.elements['numberofdays'];
var oneDay = 24*60*60*1000;

var x = dtElem1.value;
var y = dtElem2.value;
var arr1 = x.split('/');
var arr2 = y.split('/');

var dt1 = new Date();
dt1.setFullYear(arr1[2], arr1[1], arr1[0]);
var dt2 = new Date(); 
dt2.setFullYear(arr2[2], arr2[1], arr2[0]);

resultElem.value = Math.round(Math.abs((dt1.getTime() -
  dt2.getTime())/(oneDay)));
```

Comment: aren't you forgetting some quotes on lines 1 and 2?

Comment: ow sorry i use datetimepicker, i just put dates to be specific.

Comment: You can avoid `Math.abs()` if you switch `dt1` with `dt2`, because `dt2.getTime() >= dt1.getTime()` holds, or?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Date methods count months from zero, so you should substract 1 from the month number when setting the date. That explains your bug, since you end up substracting the 30th of *october* from the 1st of *november* and october has 31 days.

This will give the expected result:

```
dt1.setFullYear(arr1[2], arr1[1] - 1, arr1[0])
dt2.setFullYear(arr2[2], arr2[1] - 1, arr2[0])
```

Note that you don't need to create the Date and then set it. You can pass the same arguments directly to the constructor:

```
dt1 = new Date(arr1[2], arr1[1] - 1, arr1[0])
dt2 = new Date(arr2[2], arr2[1] - 1, arr2[0])
```